# How to Create new columns using other column Values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a column `Period_Subcategory` based on other columns' values: a dictionary of {`Period` value: [list of `Sub_Category` values...]}

Input `df`:

```
Period   Category    Sub_Category
FY18Q1   Clothing    Shirt    
FY18Q2   Clothing    Trouser
FY18Q1   Clothing    Shirt
FY18Q3   Clothing    Pant 
FY18Q1   Accessories Watch
FY18Q2   Accessories Muff
FY18Q2   Accessories Watch
FY18Q3   Accessories Chains
```

Desired output `df_output`:

```
Category    Period_Subcategory
Clothing    {'FY18Q1':'Shirt','FY18Q2':'Trouser','FY18Q3':'Pant'}
Accessories {'FY18Q1':'Watch','FY18Q2':['muff','Watch'],'FY18Q3':'Chains'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner

```
>>> df2 = df.groupby(by=["Category", "Period"]).agg(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index().groupby("Category").apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x["Period"], x["Sub_Category"])))
>>> df2
Category
Accessories    {'FY18Q1': ['Watch'], 'FY18Q2': ['Watch', 'Muf...
Clothing       {'FY18Q1': ['Shirt'], 'FY18Q2': ['Trouser'], '...
dtype: object
>>> df2.values
array([{'FY18Q1': ['Watch'], 'FY18Q2': ['Watch', 'Muff'], 'FY18Q3': ['Chains']},
       {'FY18Q1': ['Shirt'], 'FY18Q2': ['Trouser'], 'FY18Q3': ['Pant']}],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: You want `groupby(..., sort=False)` to keep the original order 'Clothing','Accessories'.

Comment: Thanks. Also the structure of values in dictionary column requested by OP was not consistent (either string or list).

Answer (score 2):

Write a function that constructs the dictionary and apply it to your dataframe, grouped by category:

```py
def make_dict(df):
    d = {}
    for period in sorted(set(df.Period)):
        d[period] = list(set(df.Sub_Category[df.Period == period]))
    return d

df_output = df.groupby('Category').apply(make_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can *nearly* get this with:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records( [(a,dict(zip(g['Period'],g['Sub_Category'])) ) for (a,g) in df.groupby('Category', group_keys=False)], columns=['Category','Period_Subcategory'] ).set_index('Category')

                                                     Period_Subcategory
Category                                                               
Accessories  {'FY18Q1': 'Watch', 'FY18Q2': 'Watch', 'FY18Q3': 'Chains'}
Clothing     {'FY18Q1': 'Shirt', 'FY18Q2': 'Trouser', 'FY18Q3': 'Pant'}
```

...except that `pd.DataFrame.from_records()` doesn't create a list, so it mishandles the duplicate for 'Accessories','FY18Q2'.